# Export (backup) and Truncate (delete) table at the same time (i.e. atomic)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-backups, mysql-backup

I am hosting a forum with "forum gold".
People trade this a lot, gift it, award people with it to "thank" or "like" posts, or to increase reputation.

However, I am concerned that there might be some exploit that allows people to hack gold into their forum account, so I added logging on EVERY forum gold transaction.

It works well. I can perform sum queries to assure that no unknown sources are introducing forum gold into the system, and to ensure that all forum gold awarded to users are accounted for.

However, it totally blew up. Within just a couple of days, I have more than 100,000 entries in the table. I also got mail from my webhost about a slow mySQL query warning, which is just a simple SELECT from that table of a single record, no joins, ordering, functions like date_add() or anything at all even.

So I want to completely export AND empty the table with the logs. Now, I normally back up the rest of my database via the "export" feature in phpmyadmin. However, this table is highly active, anywhere from 10 up to 50 new rows are added every second, but I want to keep the integrity and accuracy of my computations by not losing any records.

Is there an "atomic" way I can export then delete all records, with no transactions getting in between?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just ended up:

- creating a new TEMP table,

  selecting everything from the LOG table,

  inserting it into the new TEMP table,

  then deleting from LOG everything where exists the same record in the TEMP table

  exporting the TEMP table

  doing a global replace of "INSERT INTO `temp`" into "INSERT INTO `log`"